# what to do if i accidentally reset the computer account

Tags: windows-server-2008, accounts, password-reset

I'm not the domain admin, but I thought I could handle a simple task, and apparently I thought wrong, how I need assistance.

A computer was locked and we needed to login to shutdown a program that was locking a file.

I have done this before: I open active directory, and reset their password.

However, I reset their computer account instead.

[image]

I went ahead and reset the password, but when I enter it (Windows XP desktop/Server R2 domain) I get a message saying the account is not available (makes sense, I just don't know how to fix it).

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I have admin access..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reboot should work, since resetting the computer account password should set it to "Computername$". This is the default tried by computers that fail authentication.

Another quick fix is to remove and re-add it to the domain.

Comment: If you reset the computer account, you break the secure channel. Reboot wont work. But disjoin/rejoin will.